# How to find corresponding column value if value exists in another column of same table

Tags: mysql, sql

employee_name column has all employee names with corresponding employee_ID and and manager_ID column has all employee's employee_ID of their mangers

here i want to get all employees with their mangers_names

NOTE: manager is also an employee in a company so manager_ID ,employee_ID 
contains same values

Please see below table

```
select * from  test1.employee;

Employee_id Employee_Name  Manager_ID
1124        Annapurna      1125 
1125        Jaseel         
1126        Shilpa         1125

select employee_Name, employee_Name as manager_Name from
employee   where Employee_id  in (select Manager_ID from employee ) ;

RESULT:
employee_Name manager_Name
Jaseel         Jaseel         

select * from  test1.employee;

select employee_Name, employee_Name as manager_Name from
 employee   where Employee_id  in (select Manager_ID from employee ) ;


employee_Name manager_Name
Annapurna     jaseel
Shilpa        Annapurna
```

Comment: are you looking for first line managers? or all of them?

Comment: in table described only manager_ID of employee . iam looking to get manager names of all of them here i can get manager name from column employee_name based on employee_ID

Comment: look for `recursive with`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to search just one level up, as shown in your sample data, you could just self-join the table, like :

```
SELECT 
    t1.Employee_Name,
    t2.Employee_Name Manager_Name
FROM
    test1.employee t1
    LEFT JOIN test1.employee t2 
        ON t2.Employee_id = t1.Manager_id
```

Nb : as we are using LEFT JOIN, if an employee has no manager, it will appear in the resultset, with Manager_name as NULL.